# JavaFX. Как получить элемент по нажатию

Tags: java, javafx

Есть `TabPane`, в нем создаются `Tab`, в `Tab` помещается `TextArea`. Есть `Button`, который что-то должен делать с открытым `TextArea` в `Tab`. Как мне получить этот `TextArea`?

Думал отслеживать нажатие на элемент (не понял), или когда в фокусе становится элемент(пробовал, получалось отловить все кроме `TextArea` и `TextField`(это я к примеру)).

Привожу код метода создания Табов (Хотя вряд ли он нужен).

```
@Override
public boolean addTabOnView(TabPane tabPane, File file) {

    Tab tab = new Tab(file.getName());
    AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
    TextArea textArea = null;
    try {
        textArea = new TextArea(readFile(file));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }


    AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(textArea, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(textArea, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(textArea, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(textArea, 0.0);
    anchorPane.getChildren().add(textArea);
    tab.setContent(anchorPane);
    tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);
    return true;
}

ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

String readFile(File file) throws IOException {
    Files.lines(file.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8).forEach(a -> stringArrayList.add(a));
    String string = "";
    for (String str:stringArrayList) {
        string += str;
        string += "\n";
    }
    return string;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При условии, что наполнение таба контентом в методе `addTabOnView` не изменится, то:

```
Tab tab = tabPane.getTabs().filtered( Tab::isSelected ).get( 0 );
//или
Tab tab = tabPane.getTabs().stream().filter( Tab::isSelected ).findFirst().get();

TextArea area = (TextArea)((Parent)tab.getContent()).getChildrenUnmodifiable().get( 0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Пусть `addTabOnView(TabPane tabPane, File file)` возвращает значение созданного `textArea = new TextArea(readFile(file));` и всего делов.

Либо просто из таба забирать как то так:
`tab.getContent().getChildren().get(0);`